# Total internal reflection angle

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

For what angle does total internal reflection happen?

I think that it happens for angle=k*pi where k is an integer with the possible values: 0, 1, 2, 3...
Is my assumption correct?

Comment: total reflection of what on what?

Comment: Why are you assuming **anything** when there is such a wealth of easily accessible tutorials on Snell's law?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I think the purpose of the question is to award free reputation to whosoever answers it.

Comment: @Simha  :-) :-) . In that case, I'll give you another + !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needn't. Take a look at Snell's law, $$n_1 \sin i = n_2 \sin r$$
If you're sending a ray from an optically denser medium to a less denser one, $n_1 > n_2$. As you increase $i$, for some value, $n_1 \sin i = n_2$ (since the sine function gives values always lesser than $1$). For that value of $i$, you find that $\sin r = 1 \implies r = \frac{\pi}{2}$, which means the refracted ray skims along the outer surface of the interface of the two media. Note that beyond this value of $i$, Snell's law is not defined since it gives $\sin r > 1$ (which is not possible). It is for those values greater than this value of $i$ (known as critical angle) that total internal reflection takes place. At any angle greater than this, total internal reflection takes place, whether or not it is an integral multiple of $\pi$.